# Agora.io - When other user leave channel and rejoin, the video stream of the other user hanged/stopped updating

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, agora.io

I tried to do a video streaming application with Unity and I have successfully connect two user and are able to video chat & sharescreen. The problem is now when the other/second user press leave channel and rejoin again, first user will see the second user screen just stopped at the last frame. Only way to deal with it right now is to exit Unity play mode and re-enter again. Below are the code:

```
    void LoadEngine()
    {
        print("Loading Engine...");

        if (engine != null)
        {
            print("Engine already exists. Please unload it first!");
            return;
        }

        engine = IRtcEngine.GetEngine(appId);
        engine.SetLogFilter(LOG_FILTER.DEBUG);
    }

    void UnloadEngine()
    {
        print("Unloading Engine...");

        if (engine != null)
        {
            IRtcEngine.Destroy();
            engine = null;
        }
    }

    void EnableVideo(bool yes)
    {
        engine.DisableAudio();
        if (yes)
        {
            engine.EnableVideo();
            engine.EnableVideoObserver();
        }
        else
        {
            engine.DisableVideo();
            engine.DisableVideoObserver();
        }
    }

    private void JoinChannel()
    {
        print("Joining Channel...");

        EnableVideo(true);

        // add our callback to handle Agora events
        engine.OnJoinChannelSuccess += OnJoinChannelSuccess;
        engine.OnUserJoined += OnUserJoined;
        engine.OnUserOffline += OnUserLeave;
        engine.OnLeaveChannel += OnLeaveChannel;

        button_Join.onClick.RemoveListener(JoinChannel);
        button_Join.onClick.AddListener(LeaveChannel);
        button_Join.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Leave Channel";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(channelName))
        {
            return;
        }

        engine.JoinChannel(channelName, null, 0);
    }

    private void LeaveChannel()
    {
        print("Leaving Channel...");

        button_Join.onClick.RemoveListener(LeaveChannel);
        button_Join.onClick.AddListener(JoinChannel);
        button_Join.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Join Channel";

        playerOne.Clear();
        playerTwo.Clear();

        engine.LeaveChannel();
        EnableVideo(false);

        engine.OnJoinChannelSuccess -= OnJoinChannelSuccess;
        engine.OnUserJoined -= OnUserJoined;
        engine.OnUserOffline -= OnUserLeave;
        engine.OnLeaveChannel -= OnLeaveChannel;
    }

    private void OnJoinChannelSuccess(string channelName, uint uid, int elapsed)
    {
        print("Joined with uid " + uid);
        myId = uid;
        playerOne.Set(0);
    }

    private void OnUserJoined(uint uid, int elapsed)
    {
        string userJoinedMessage = string.Format("onUserJoined callback uid {0} with elapsed {1}", uid, elapsed);
        print(userJoinedMessage);

        playerTwo.Set(uid);
    }

    private void OnUserLeave(uint uid, USER_OFFLINE_REASON reason)
    {
        string userLeaveMessage = string.Format("onUserOffline callback uid {0} with reason {1}", uid, reason);
        print(userLeaveMessage);

        playerTwo.Clear();
    }

    private void OnLeaveChannel(RtcStats stats)
    {
        playerTwo.Clear();
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        UnloadEngine();
    }
```

Is there anything I missed out in the code?

***Edit***

I suspect this is Agora API bugs where the video surface will not continue to stream the video when the UID was being changed in the runtime. This explained when the same user leave and rejoin, he will get different uid everytime he rejoin. The video surface will need to set UID to another number which causes the video surface stopped streaming.

***Solution***

I solved it using unity instantiate to real time instantiate the video surface when connected to channel and destroy the video surface game object when leaving a channel.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, I want to swap my large raw image to a smaller raw image to represent both the remote and local user, respectively. If I use SetForUser() method, the raw image freezes and tmpi always returns -1

Answer (score 0):

first of all, great name! ;)

I'm glad that you were able to work out a solution. 
Another technique you can try, is calling:
`yourVideoSurface.SetForUser(yourNewUID);`

It looks like you're already implicitly doing that in your `playerOne.Set(0)` call, however I'd figure I'd mention it just in case.

Comment: I am calling `SetForUser()` on my VideoSurface and the video still freezes when other user leaves and rejoins.  Looks like `videoRender.UpdateVideoRawData()` is returning -1 when called with the updated uid, which causes `VideoSurface.Update()` to abort before modifying its texture.  Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: @Jeremy My guess is that you're calling SetForUser() with an old UID. When a user leaves/rejoins they join with a new unique UID. 
I'd recommend deleting and reinstantiating the Image whenever a new user joins.


Here is a [link to a github project you can use as reference](https://github.com/joelthomas362/agora-mmo-videochat-demo) that allows players to leave/join at will.  I hope that it helps!

Comment: No, I'm printing the UID in the log and it's definitely different each time.  Rejoining isn't even a special case; I have a surface pre-made before anyone has joined, and set its UID to whoever joined most recently.  Works the first time and not the second time.  Looks a lot like VideoSurface simply doesn't support changing users (even though the interface implies it does).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Unity.  The tmp was returning -1.  In the Update loop of VideoSurface.cs if this occurs, the update loop stops.

```
if (tmpi == -1)
return;
```

I agree with Jeremy, the Agora VideoSurface doesn't support changing users.  I set the UID on the VideoSurface manually and it fixed the issue.  I also agree that the sdk implies that it would change- which is misleading and frustrating.

I believe the issue may occur because VideoSurface.cs sets uint `uid = mUid;` in the update loop, so it is set to the default ID when the Unity scene starts then errors out when `videoSurface.SetForUser(uid);` is called by TestHelloUnityVideo when a user joins.